# how to go to new server i just created - WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I downloaded and installed wampserver and created a new server with password protection in

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/
```

after then I saved it and then went back to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

but it doesnt give me a login screen it just goes to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/#PMAURL-0:index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=49757a6780b2bd2aaa67f69e0f630cf1
```

and at the top it says

```
Server: mysql wampserver
```

so my question is how do i select my server i just created or am i doing something wrong

Comment: Have you restarted wamp? Click on the wamp logo and restart all services.

Comment: I did but it didn't work

Comment: I don't think WAMP will provide individual server for your projects, the credentials you made is just for phpmyadmin to "secure" your database but this doesn't really matter if you're just doing your project locally. Every projects will go under www folder.

Comment: i did download the phpmyadmin folder and put in www directory but then i get a new problem with it everytime i want to create a server i dont get the "PHP extension to use" and it automatically saves it as mysqli and when i go to login screen i put my details and it doesnt work

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Good dat here: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,86930,page=1

Comment: just trying to create a new server @nCore

Comment: no its not dat problem i do get an access i just don't get the login page @user3250974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think this is just a terminology problem, but lets start by getting a few things straight.

First phpMyAdmin is a tool for maintaining a MYSQL database. You are not creating a server when you create a database.

So if you used phpMyAdmin and changed the password for the `root` userid then of course you have to tell phpMyAdmin the password when you try and login next time.

There are 2 ways to do this, well there are more than 2 ways but lets keep it simple for now.

First way :-

Edit the \wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php file and find this lines

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Change this lines to include your new password

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD';
```

Restart the Apache server :-

```
left click wampmanager icon -> Apache -> Service -> Restart service
```

The run phpMyAdmin

```
left click wampmanager icon -> phpMyAdmin
```

and you should be automatically logged in.

Personally I dont like this method as you have to hard code the password into a php file that theoretically anybody could see.

So my prefered method to :-

Edit the \wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\config.inc.php file and make these 2 changes

From

```
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

To

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
```

This will tell phpMyAdmin to throw a login screen where you can enter the

```
username = root
password = YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD
```

Also, remember there are actually 3 `root` user accounts setup in a default WAMPServer MYSQL installation. Where a MYSQL account has 2 parts seperated by an `@` symbol `username` @ `domain`

```
root@localhost
root@127.0.0.1
root@::1
```

If you have changed the password on only one of these make sure you are logging in using the same using the correct URL like so :-

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin
```

or

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

or

```
http://::1/phpmyadmin
```

Then make sure you change all 3 account to have the same password so this does not trip you up later.